# Twitter API bearer token request returns forbidden

Tags: asp-classic, twitter, oauth-2.0

Simple pull of search tweets needed an I'm getting stuck trying to obtain a bearer token via a classic ASP post.

The server is responding with 403 Unable to verify your credentials

I'm obviously fluid on ASP server side form post so any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
Dim consumerKey,consumerSecret,myCstr
consumerKey = "abc..."
consumerSecret = "123..."
myCstr = base64_encode(consumerKey & ":" & consumerSecret)
myAuth = "Basic "&myCstr    

Dim xmlhttp 
Set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST","https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token",false    
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent","HTTP/1.1"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", myAuth
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
xmlhttp.send "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it... I needed two equal signs at the end of the end of the base64 string.

That wasn't really very clear in the twitter API docs.